# How to create a more restrictive generic constraint in inherited class

Tags: c#

```
public class Foo<T> where T:struct, Enum, Iimmutable
public class Bar<T>:Foo<T> where T:Iimmutable //No
public class Bar:Foo<Iimmutable> //No
```

I thought this might be allowed, considering that the base class provides 3 options for constraints, and I need a *more* constrained derived class of just *one* of the matching constraints.

I get a compiler warning. It seems as if all `Bar<Iimmutable>` satisfy `Foo<T>` constraints. Can you suggest what to do, I need the functionality of the base class with the derived class constraint of `Iimmutable`...

Comment: you need to add all contraints to derived class, because it not inherits automatically, so you need `Bar<T>: Foo<T> where T:struct, Enum, Iimmutable`

Comment: @Rodrigo I figured that, but the design intent is like this: "base class handles low level system immutables, while the derived class handles high level Iimmutables which are classes designed to provide an immutable value." Therefore the derived class should not be dealing with low level structs.

Comment: the derived class is a specification of the base class type, so you cant remove the constraints of base class, because of OOP inheritance concept. You can just add contraints, not remove them. Like `Bar<T>: Foo<T> where T: struct, Enum, Iimmutable, IAnotherInterface` will work fine. Try to think about if you have a Foo<T> variable, a Bar<T> value can be assigned to it, like `Foo<T> x = new Bar<T>()`, so imagine if Foo<> and Bar<> had different constraints? It will not work and the code will not compile.

Comment: There's no way anything that satisfies the `struct, Enum` constraint (any enum type, but not `Enum` itself) can also satisfy the `Iimmutable` constraint.  Enums can't implement interfaces. It will let you declare the `Foo<T>` class like this but you can't use the type with anything for `T` because nothing can satisfy all constraints.

Comment: Ok thanks, I can see now that generic constraints are signatures that must match. I thought it was OR and not AND gate logic

Comment: Careful using the word "siganture" there, because constraints are not part of method signatures and overload resolution does not consider generic type constraints. You're talking about types, though, and types don't have signatures, at least not as a term used to describe classes, so you're going to get confused and/or confuse others with that word in that context.

Comment: @NWoodsman: it's very much an AND (not an OR).